# How would i store a value from a constantly changing value and compare the stored one against the chaning one in C?

Tags: c

So i'm trying to figure out how much Y a player has fallen in a game to then figure out how much damage should be taken. I'm doing this by trying to store the current y position of a player when they aren't on the ground, getting the new y position then subtracting the new position with the old one. Problem is oldy is always set to the current y and i don't know how to keep it separate. I don't have a lot of experience with C so any help would be appreciated

```
if (player->grounded==false){
player->blocksfallen=player->position.y-player->oldy;
player->oldy=player->position.y;
} else {
    player->blocksfallen=0;
}
```

Comment: new variable: `originaly`

Comment: Yes with the code you show `oldy` will be set to the value of the current `y`. *But* the next time this code is executed, then `oldy` will be the *previous* value of `y`. So `player->position.y-player->oldy` will be "current value of y - old value of y".

Comment: Or are you trying to store the *first* value of `y`? Then just store it the first time, and never change it.

Comment: Sounds like you want `blocksfallen += y - oldy;` ..  And if you're not falling, you do `blocksfallen = 0;` -- in essence, you can probably fix your code by adding a `+`.  Then you can add some whitespace to make it readable.  One thing to note is that if these values are floating-point, you might lose precision by doing multiple additions of deltas.  In that case, you'd benefit from storing the position where your player first started falling, and subtract that from the ground when they finally hit it.

Comment: Consider making a [mre] (MRE) which has the player fall and then stop falling and just needs the calculation of damage. This is interesting because I am pretty sure that you have mechamisms in your code which would make things easier and which would be visible in such a MRE.

Answer (score 0):

The damage should depend on the speed with which the ground is hit, not by the height fallen, though there is a relation between those.
The relation is not 1:1, consider somebody starting to fall with already a downward speed, e.g. being thrown downwards. Or the other direction, the speed might be slowed by something like a parachute.

Inside the code this translates to having a variable with (at least the vertical component of) the speed. Increase it for acceleration, decrease it for any breaking effects (more precisely phrased: increase it less for breaking effects).
When you hit the ground, calculate damage based on the speed at that point.
Introducing that speed variable will also solve your problem in the absence of thrown characters and parachutes. It is then something of an accumulator of accelearation, which is very close to an accumulator of distance fallen - just easier to update. You just need to increase it by the gravity-caused acceleration each turn/frame/animation-step.

This means to turn the calculation around. Instead of trying to calculate the speed/total-height/damage from the previous height andcurrent height, you calculate the current height from previous height + speed. If you look at how you calculate the current height form previous you will notice that you already do something similar there (let's say I am pretty sure you do, though it is not seen in the shown code, something like height=height-speedconstant).

Comment: Well this would be Newton's 2nd law of motion... explaining it is a job for https://physics.stackexchange.com/ and not this programming site here. Raw graphics programming does involve a whole lot of physics.

Comment: @Lundin  I consider my answer to provide a solution for the programming problem described, motivated by just a little physics. The solution proposal discusses variables and algorithms and cold be applied even without reference to the physics view point. You are not saying that this is physics-only, are you?

Comment: a y velocity check is already in place somewhere else in the code so thats why i only included the stuff about the height

Comment: If you are aware of the y-velocity, what relation or difference to you see between that velocity and the `player->position.y-player->oldy` in your code? What conflict or difference do you see between that velocity and the accumulation like `+=player->position.y-player->oldy` as in the comment by paddy or the more physics-based solution in my answer? Where is the remaining obstacle that keeps you from using the precise proposal by paddy with the help of the explanation in my answer? If you explain what keeps you, then paddy or I might be able to provide the needed additional insight.

Comment: i would like to use blocks fallen along with y velocity to then figure out how much damage should be taken. i would also like for it to ignore if the player fell less then 4 blocks though it would probably be better to see how much velocity you get when falling 4 blocks, might just base everything off y velocity and drop blocksfallen entirely

Comment: Yes, now you got it.